# treatment progress percentage

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I use QGIS SCRIT 2.14

When I run the script I would like to see the progress percentage

```
##Input_raster1=raster
##Band_raster1=output raster
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import os
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import numpy
import sys
import osr
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
ds = gdal.Open(Input_raster1, GA_ReadOnly)
dst_ds_red = driver.Create(Band_raster1, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 1, GDT_Float32)
dst_ds_red.SetProjection( ds.GetProjection())
geotransform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
if not geotransform is None:
  st_ds_red.SetGeoTransform( geotransform )
bandList = []
band = ds.GetRasterBand(2)
data = band.ReadAsArray()
bandList.append(data)
rasterlayer_red = numpy.zeros((ds.RasterYSize, ds.RasterXSize), dtype=numpy.float32)
for i in range (0, ds.RasterXSize):
  for j in range (0, ds.RasterYSize):
    RED = (float(bandList[0][j][i]))
    rasterlayer_red[j][i] = RED
dst_ds_red.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(rasterlayer_red)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some answer on the [QGIS Script processing documentation page](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#communicating-with-the-user) :

> **Communicating with the user**
>
> If your algorithm takes a long time to
> process, it is a good idea to inform the user. You have a global named
> progress available, with two available methods: **setText(text)** and
> **setPercentage(percent)** to modify the progress text and the progress
> bar.
>
> If you have to provide some information to the user, not related to
> the progress of the algorithm, you can use the **setInfo(text)** method,
> also from the progress object.
>
> If your script has some problem, the correct way of propagating it is
> to raise an exception of type GeoAlgorithmExecutionException(). You
> can pass a message as argument to the constructor of the exception.
> Processing will take care of handling it and communicating with the
> user, depending on where the algorithm is being executed from
> (toolbox, modeler, Python console...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fish/
- https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar

Or just create your own with `sys` and `time` modules.